# error with small integer in fraction both arguments should be Rational instances

Tags: python, integer, fractions

there is two small digit like `1.012345e10` in fraction in python but got error `both should be rational parameters` and if it convert to integer it change to zero.

```
from fractions import Fraction
import math
pole=input('which pole is your choosen ? monopole , dipole , quadpole : ')
e=1602e-22
epsi=885e-14
#pi=314e-2
if pole=='monopole':
   x=input("Enter value for 'x' parameter : ")
   x=int(x)
   y=input("Enter value for 'y' parameter : ")
   y=int(y)
   z=input("Enter value for 'z' parameter : ")
   z=int(z)
   n=input("Enter value for n in 'q=n*e' sentence : ")
   n=int(n)
   q=n*(e)
   r=math.sqrt(pow(x,2)+pow(y,2)+pow(z,2))
   g=(4*math.pi*epsi)  #g=1.1121237993707868e-10
   v=fractions.Fraction((-1),(g)) * fractions.Fraction((q),(r))  
   print('v=',v,'r=',r,'q=',q,sep='\n')
```

got this error :

```
  --> 174             raise TypeError("both arguments should be "
      175                             "Rational instances")
      176
```

if calculate 'v' parameter in form of this:

```
      v=Fraction(('-1'),('1.1121237993707868e-10')) * Fraction((q),(r))
```

still has same error.

Comment: You should include a minimum working example as your code so we can help solve it.

Comment: Pi isn't rational, so things aren't looking great.

Answer (score 0):

1. the python package you are using only supports integer inputs,
   [or it converts into integers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GgNux.jpg).

   [link for the source code](https://github.com/bradley101/fraction/blob/master/fraction/Fraction.py)

   that is why to error says; both parameters must be rational.
2. in python, by default floating-point number, round-off to the nearest lower integer. that is why you got zero after using int().
3. you can use python library called [decimal](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/decimal.html)

Answer (score 0):

change my code to form of below and it worked !

```
from fractions import Fraction
import math
pole=input('which pole is your choosen ? monopole , dipole , quadpole : ')
e=1602e-22
epsi=885e-14
#pi=314e-2
if pole=='monopole ': 
    x=input("Enter value for 'x' parameter : ")
    x=int(x)
    y=input("Enter value for 'y' parameter : ")
    y=int(y)
    z=input("Enter value for 'z' parameter : ")
    z=int(z)
    n=input("Enter value for n in 'q=n*e' sentence : ")
    n=int(n)
    q=n*(e)
    r=math.sqrt(pow(x,2)+pow(y,2)+pow(z,2))
    g=(4*math.pi*epsi)
    v=(Fraction( Fraction(-1),Fraction(4*math.pi*epsi) )) * (Fraction(Fraction(q),Fraction(r) )) 
    print('v=',v,'r=',r,'q=',q,sep='\n')
```

this is Result:

```
  which pole is your choosen ? monopole , unipole , quadpole : monopole 
  Enter value for 'x' parameter : 2
  Enter value for 'y' parameter : 3
  Enter value for 'z' parameter : 4
  Enter value for n in 'q=n*e' sentence : 5
  v= -23258980343779986243584/17390428744443997208254875991145
  r= 5.385164807134504
  q= 8.01e-19
```

hope this is useful and be correct!